# Paytm payment gateway in PHP

Tags: php

When I integrate Paytm payment gateway I downloaded Paytmkit. When I copied form code(TxnTest.php) and paste it on my coding page, then form code work perfectly but if I use some my input fields and then POST the value to (pgRedirect.php) and created Array as well then error is shown:

> Checksum Mismatch Error.

under the `<form>` tag

```
<input type="text" title1="PRODUCT" name="PRODUCT" value="<?php echo $_POST['hidden_product'];?>">pro.PNG 3
```

Then I POST the value to (pgRedirect.php) -> `$PRODUCT = $_POST['PRODUCT'];` After that I create an Array to (pgRedirect.php) -> `$paramList["PRODUCT"] = $PRODUCT;`

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: under the <form> tag
       
  <input type="text" title1="PRODUCT" name="PRODUCT" value="<?php echo $_POST['hidden_product'];?>">pro.PNG

3- Then I  POST the value to (pgRedirect.php)
       ->   $PRODUCT = $_POST['PRODUCT'];
   After that I create an Array to (pgRedirect.php)
       ->   $paramList["PRODUCT"] = $PRODUCT;

Comment: Please use the [edit] button and don't post code in comments. No idea if I copied your code correctly because tt doesn't look correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all payment providers require a checksum, created with the aid of a key they provide.

This checksum is usually simply a concatted string of all fields and their values, then pulled through the checksum hasher.

In the paytm documentation you can see the example here of the php implementation(Click the php tab)

https://developer.paytm.com/docs/checksum/#ValidateChecksum

> In form post, create the checksumhash using your account's merchant key and all of the API request parameters.

```php
* import checksum generation utility */
require_once("./PaytmChecksum.php");

/* initialize an array */
$paytmParams = array();

/* add parameters in Array */
$paytmParams["MID"] = "YOUR_MID_HERE";
$paytmParams["ORDERID"] = "YOUR_ORDERID_HERE";

/**
* Generate checksum by parameters we have
* Find your Merchant Key in your Paytm Dashboard at https://dashboard.paytm.com/next/apikeys 
*/
$paytmChecksum = PaytmChecksum::generateSignature($paytmParams, 'YOUR_MERCHANT_KEY');
echo sprintf("generateSignature Returns: %s\n", $paytmChecksum);
```

So in short, make sure that all your `$paytmParams` are put in the correct array for the checksum computation. If you have extra fields that you submit, you need to add them to the array before computing the checksum.